# Итерация нескольких векторов по очереди (Rust)

Tags: rust, итераторы

```
let fruits = vec!["apple", "banana", "orange"];
let cities = vec!["moscow", "berlin", "paris"];
let colors = vec!["red", "green", "blue"];
```

Как реализовать итерацию в таком порядке?

```
> apple
> moscow
> red
> banana
> berlin
> green
```

Как реализовать такую итерацию с произвольным количеством итерируемых объектов произвольной длины?

Comment: Например [itertools::izip](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.izip.html) (если сама идея использования zip подходит для вашей задачи)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. itertools::izip

###### cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
itertools = "0.10"
```

###### main.rs

```rust
use itertools::izip;


fn main() {
    let fruits = vec!["apple", "banana", "orange"];
    let cities = vec!["moscow", "berlin", "paris"];
    let colors = vec!["red", "green", "blue"];

    for (fruit, city, color) in izip!(fruits, cities, colors) {
        println!("{fruit}\n{city}\n{color}");
    }
}
```

### 2. итерирование через индекс:

```rust
let fruits = vec!["apple", "banana", "orange"];
let cities = vec!["moscow", "berlin", "paris"];
let colors = vec!["red", "green", "blue"];

for i in 0..colors.len() {
    println!(
        "{}\n{}\n{}\n",
        fruits.get(i).unwrap_or(&""),  //  На случай, если длины 
        cities.get(i).unwrap_or(&""),  //  итерируемых объектов
        colors.get(i).unwrap_or(&"")   //  не совпадают.
    );
}
```